# Which method is accessible when moved to previous View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have 2 views:

In the first view I have added another view:

```
[self.view addSubView:self.secondView];
```

In Second View when i Press Back then i have remove the second view for back to the first View

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

but in my first view there is the UITableView I have to use `[UITableView reloadData];` method of UITableView but I don't know which method is called when secondView is removed.

My main objective is to call some method when I remove the second view and call any method which will reload the data.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewDidAppear` for your first view to call `[UITableView reloadData];`.  It should be called each time that view appears.

Comment: I have Check but nothing Log ... :( - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
}

Answer (score 1):

You should use viewWillAppear as it will not refresh while the user is looking at it.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear{
   [super viewWillAppear];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this not works for me .. i have tried this because in my delegate its UIViewController in the base view so when i remove the second view their is no view delegates call :(